# When She Loved Me: Decorative Chords alternatives on (Add2)

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, analysis

This is the middle part of "When She Loved Me," in *Toy Story 2* sung by Sarah McLachlan.

P.S. See this [for example for the piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1Bsd6RwYVk).

The chord progression goes twice as:

Em7b5 -> A/C# - > Dm -> F(add2)/C -> Bb(add2).

My questions:

Why does the song writer consider the (add 2) decorations? It sounds a bit messy and not clear. How will it be (or why not) to replace the follows:

1. replace F(add2)/C (namely CFGA) to F/C (namely CFA)?
2. replace Bb(add2) (namely BbCDF) to Bb (namely BbDF)?
3. replace Em7b5 (EGBbD) to Em7 (EGBD)?

---

### For more information on the sheet music:

The first time:

[image: "When She Loved Me", portion with lyrics: "Ev-'ry hour we spent to-geth-er | lives with-in my heart"]

Repeat the second time:

[image: "When She Loved Me", portion with lyrics: "and when she was hap-py so__ was I]

Comment: Both this and the linked question suggest an unfamiliarity with these kinds of harmonies. They're common in jazz, musical theater and movies, and singer/songwriter kinds of popular music.  Before continuing to look to analyze these kinds of chords/chord progressions, I highly recommend spending several months listening to this kind of music so that your ear can get used to it. Once you have a feel for the language, the analysis will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

#### Em7b5 vs. Em7

The song is temporarily in D minor here. Em7b5 is the ii7 chord in D minor; whereas Em7 is the ii7 chord in D major. D minor is the relative minor of F major, so the Bb has already been prominent in our ear throughout the piece.

#### Fadd2/C vs. F/C

The G in this chord is a carryover from the melody G that comes with "hap-py". I interpret it as hanging onto that memory of happiness in a way that transitions the lyrical subject from "she" to "I". Without that G, there's no melding of the two characters, just a sharp transition from one to the other.

(Note: In an earlier version of this answer, I proposed this chord as Csus4. This was based on changing the F to E (i.e., resolving the suspension) on the "and" of beat 4. However, this is wrong. What I really did was changed the chord to A minor, which sounds quite nice, but isn't what's happening here.)

#### Bb(add2) vs. Bb

The "add2" is a carryover from the previous chord and adds a gentle dissonance against both the Bb and the D. Were in "just" a Bb chord, that poignancy would be missing.

(Note: in an early version of this answer I claimed the Bbsus2 would be a better label. This is incorrect. Although the C is "suspended" from the previous chord, both the Bb and D — that is, the tones of resolution — are present in the Bb chord. Thus, the apparent suspension is a color tone rather than a dissonance requiring resolution.)

Comment: I'm not your mystery downvoter, this is a one-time thing. I'll explain why I happened to vote that way: my downvote is because I disagree with you on the second and third paragraphs. In the second paragraph, the Csus4 interpretation misses the A note of the Fadd2, and while Dm C Bb is a common progression, I think it is more accurate to examine the V-I F-Bb motion while using the descending bass motion to encompass the points in your paragraphs. The viability of Fadd2 can be established by changing beat 4 to an F7 chord. It also perfectly explains the melody without non-chord-tone analysis.

Comment: I also disagree with the Bbsus2 interpretation of paragraph 3. I see no issue with the Bbadd2 label, and to me the D note is clearly the chord tone. No need to exclude the note D from the chord label, in my opinion - it can all be in the Bbadd2, or honestly a simple Bb major triad is better for non-chord-tone analysis. So as to why I downvoted? It's because I disagree with a large portion of your answer. Nothing personal, I hope. And I'd be open to a discussion on the merits of our different interpretations, if you want to go to chat.

Comment: Good.  Now, what about the F(add2)?  I still challenge you on that!

Comment: @LaurencePayne I stand by that one. I think it's a C major chord in disguise, and I don't think the A is structural (though I could be persuaded to go with C6, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Em7♭5 keeps us in the tonality of F major/D minor. A B♮ would take the music somewhere it doesn't want to go at that point.

The add2 chords are just an artistic decision.  You might consider them cheesy, Newman thinks the add to the emotion.   Fine, you write your music, he writes his.

And the printed chord names are fine.  In Fadd2/C  the A is as structural - the melody of that bar outlines the tonic chord of the piece.  And a chord containing B♭, F, C and D  is an (add2) not a (sus2).